# why two sql giving different result?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am confused here This first sql-

I have one entry in my `cnt_content` table with `content_pk=5419441` and `title=test wls-2`

Now when I am running this sql 1-

```
SELECT
   title,
   content_pk 
FROM
   cnt_content c 
WHERE
   c.type not in (
      'AMT', 'LPA', 'QUE'
   ) 
   AND c.private_flag = 'N' 
   AND c.searchable_flag = 'Y' 
   AND c.status in (
      'PUB', 'NAP'
   ) 
   AND (
      trim(c.title) LIKE 'test wls-2' 
      OR trim(c.special_keyword) LIKE 'test wls-2'
   )  
   and not exists (
      SELECT
         1 
      FROM
         cmd_content_metadata cmd 
      WHERE
         cmd.content_pk=5419441 
         AND cmd.for_others='Y' 
   )  
ORDER BY
   c.last_modified_date desc;
```

it is giving result-`content_pk=5419441` and `title=test wls-2`

But when I am running this sql 2-

```
SELECT
   title,
   content_pk 
FROM
   cnt_content c 
WHERE
   c.type not in (
      'AMT', 'LPA', 'QUE'
   ) 
   AND c.private_flag = 'N' 
   AND c.searchable_flag = 'Y' 
   AND c.status in (
      'PUB', 'NAP'
   ) 
   AND (
      trim(c.title) LIKE 'test wls-2' 
      OR trim(c.special_keyword) LIKE 'test wls-2'
   )  
   and not exists (
      SELECT
         1 
      FROM
         cmd_content_metadata cmd 
      WHERE
         cmd.content_pk=c.content_pk 
         AND cmd.for_others='Y' 
   )  
ORDER BY
   c.last_modified_date desc;
```

It is not giving any result. Anyone please explain.

Comment: Because there is difference in 2 queries. Please take a look here "cmd.content_pk=5419441" is in first query & in 2nd it is "cmd.content_pk=c.content_pk".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because in one you just giving specific value for content_pk as `5419441`, while other one uses corelated query which means for each and every value of content_pk selected in outer query, you are checking for equality in your sub select query.